# ECS on EC2 cluster CDK stack - What is a graceful way to handle AMI updates to cluster instances?

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-ecs, aws-cdk

For my ECS stacks using EC2 clusters , I am struggling here finding an decent way to rotate instances to the new most recent AMI without downtime. I know with ECS this has always been a little messy issue but the added complexity of CDK - Cloudformation is making this impossible for me.

If i simply update the AMI for my Autoscaling group by passing in a new ID :

```
        InstanceType: awsec2.NewInstanceType(jsii.String(envProps.AsgInstanceType)),
        MachineImage: awsec2.MachineImage_GenericLinux(&imageMap, &awsec2.GenericLinuxImageProps{}),
        //DesiredCapacity: jsii.Number(envAsgSize), //Don't set for prod and probably others
        Vpc:      vpc,
        Role: instanceRole,
    })
```

This will synth in CDK but the CFN changeset will fail. It will successfully create new launch configurations but will fail to update the ASG.

I realize i probably can not allow Cloudformation to make this update and expect it to go smoothly, so what is the best operation procedure to keep CDK and CFN in line with some kind of auto/manual instance update replacement process.

I.e. i'm imagining something like this

-Edit (overwrite) the launch configs (here is a problem because I cant overwrite the existing one and CDK will create a new one with a specific random name)
-Perform the ASG update - launch an instance - kill an instance - etc till the cluster instances are replaced with the new ones
-Update CDK - CFN to align with what exists

But this itself seems super wonky - there has to be a better way... right?

I have read all the solutions with Lambda etc but none of these resolve my CDK issue and they seem more complex than is necessary.

Comment: What you have should work if everything else is configured correctly. What error message do you get on failure?

Comment: 2023-05-26 10:44:24 UTC-0400 DevCoreEcsStack 
UPDATE_ROLLBACK_IN_PROGRESS
The following resource(s) failed to update: [devAsgASG2AA0D5CE].
2023-05-26 10:44:22 UTC-0400 devAsgASG2AA0D5CE 
UPDATE_FAILED
Group did not stabilize. {current/minSize/maxSize} group size = {3/1/1}.  -but i never set a min or max size in CDK -

Comment: Are the new intstances failing to launch? Are you using an [update policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-attribute-updatepolicy.html) with `cfn-signal`?

Comment: I'm doing all of this through CDK, i'll have to see if i can figure out how to set an update policy there. Also i'm using ECS capacity providers to manage the ASG size. Now i'm just stuck in a CFN rollback failed state... :(